# Latex Table condensed and too small?

Tags: tables, longtable

I am trying to draw a table using Tabular environment but in vain. The table is too small and the fontsize too. I am trying to make a bigger table using all the paper. Any help is really appreciated. I get the following result: [image][image] and this is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont} 
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{systeme}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[right=2cm,left=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        $\mathbf{N}^{\circ}$ & Notion définie & Définition \\
        \hline
        D 5.1 & \begin{tabular}{l}
            Produit scalaire dans un \\
            espace préhilbertien \\
        \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l}
            $H$ espace vectoriel complexe muni du produit \\
            scalaire \textbackslash langle\textbackslash rangle , application $\{H \times H \rightarrow \mathbb{C},(x, y) \mapsto\langle x, y\rangle\}$, \\
            vérifiant \\
            (i) $\forall x \in H,\langle x, x\rangle \geq 0$ \\
            (ii) $\forall x, y \in H, \forall \lambda \in \mathbb{C},\langle x+\lambda y, z\rangle=\langle x, z\rangle+\lambda\langle y, z\rangle$ \\
            (iii) $\forall x, y \in H,\langle y, x\rangle=\overline{\langle x, y\rangle}$ (complexe conjugué de \\
            $\quad\langle x, y\rangle)$ \\
            (iv) $[\langle x, x\rangle=0] \Leftrightarrow[x=0]$. \\
        \end{tabular} \\
        \hline
        D 5.2 & \begin{tabular}{l}
            Norme || || associée au produit \\
            scalaire \\
        \end{tabular} & $\|x\|=\langle x, x\rangle^{1 / 2}$ pour $H$ selon (D 5.1). \\
        \hline
        D 5.3 & Espace de Hilbert $H$ & \begin{tabular}{l}
            Espace préhilbertien $H$ selon (D 5.1), de Banach \\
            (D 1.7) pour la norme associée. \\
        \end{tabular} \\
        \hline
        D 5.4 & $x$ et $y$ orthogonaux, $x \perp y$ & $H$ préhilbertien, $x, y \in H,\langle x, y\rangle=0$. \\
        \hline
        D 5.5 & \begin{tabular}{l}
            Sous-ensembles $M$ et $N$ \\
            orthogonaux, $M \perp N$ \\
        \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l}
            $H$ espace préhilbertien, $M \subset H, N \subset H$, \\
            $\forall x \in M, \forall y \in N,\langle x, y\rangle=0$. \\
        \end{tabular} \\
        \hline
        D 5.6 & $M$ orthogonal, $M^{\perp}$ & \begin{tabular}{l}
            $H$ espace préhilbertien, $M \subset H$, \\
            $M^{\perp}=\{y \in H ; \forall x \in M,\langle x, y\rangle=0\}$. \\
        \end{tabular} \\
        \hline
        D 5.7 & \begin{tabular}{l}
            $M$ et $N$ supplémentaires \\
            orthogonaux dans $H, H=M \oplus N$ \\
            ou $M \oplus^{\perp} N$ somme directe \\
            orthogonale \\
        \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l}
            $H$ est un espace de Hilbert, $M$ et $N$ sont deux \\
            sous-espaces fermés de $H$ orthogonaux entre eux, \\
            $H=M \oplus N$, on note aussi $H=M \oplus^{\perp} N$, la norme sur \\
            $H$ est équivalente à celle fixée dans (D 1.12). \\
        \end{tabular} \\
        \hline
        D 5.8 & \begin{tabular}{l}
            Projection orthogonale $y$ de $x$ \\
            sur $M, y=P_{M X}$ \\
        \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l}
            $H$ espace préhilbertien, $M$ sous-espace vectoriel \\
            complet de $H, x \in H$ \\
            Pour $H=M \oplus^{\perp} N$, selon (D 5.7), \\
            $x=y+z, y \in M, z \in N$. \\
        \end{tabular} \\
        \hline
        D 5.9 & Ensemble orthogonal $J$ & \begin{tabular}{l}
            $H$ espace préhilbertien, $J \subseteq H$, \\
            $\forall x, y \in J, x \neq y$, on $a\langle x, y\rangle=0$. \\
        \end{tabular} \\
        \hline
        D 5.10 & \begin{tabular}{l}
            Ensemble orthonormal J \\
            (ou orthonormé) \\
        \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l}
            $H$ espace préhilbertien, $J \subseteq H, J$ orthogonal et \\
            $\forall x \in J,\|x\|=1$. \\
        \end{tabular} \\
        \hline
        D 5.11 & Ensemble total $J$ & \begin{tabular}{l}
            $H$ espace de Hilbert, $J \subseteq H$, \\
            Vect $(J)$, sous-espace vectoriel fermé engendré par \\
            $J$, est $H$ entier. \\
        \end{tabular} \\
        \hline
        D 5.12 & Base orthonormale $B$ & \begin{tabular}{l}
            $H$ espace de Hilbert, $B$ ensemble orthonormal et \\
            total. \\
        \end{tabular} \\
        \hline
        D 5.13 & Espace de Hilbert séparable & \begin{tabular}{l}
            $H$ espace de Hilbert, \\
            il existe une base orthonormale $B$ au plus \\
            dénombrable. \\
        \end{tabular} \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        $\mathbf{N}^{\circ}$ & Désignation & Énoncé \\
        \hline
        P 5.1 & \begin{tabular}{l}
            Le fameux théorème de \\
            Pythagore \\
        \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l}
            $H$ espace préhilbertien, $x, y \in H$ \\
            $[\langle x, y\rangle=0] \Rightarrow\left[\|x+y\|^{2}=\|x\|^{2}+\|y\|^{2}\right]$. \\
        \end{tabular} \\
        \hline
        P 5.2 & Règle du parallélogramme & \begin{tabular}{l}
            $H$ espace préhilbertien, $x, y \in H$, \\
            $\|x+y\|^{2}+\|x-y\|^{2}=2\left(\|x\|^{2}+\|y\|^{2}\right)$. \\
        \end{tabular} \\
        \hline
        P 5.3 & Règle de polarisation & \begin{tabular}{l}
            espace préhilbertien, $x, y \in H$ \\
            $4\langle x, y\rangle=\sum \alpha\|x+\alpha y\|^{2} ; \alpha=1,-1, i,-i$. \\
        \end{tabular} \\
        \hline
        P 5.4 & \begin{tabular}{l}
            Inégalité de Schwarz \\
            ou bien de Cauchy-Schwarz \\
        \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l}
            espace préhilbertien, $\forall x, y \in H$, \\
            $|\langle x, y\rangle| \leq\|x\|\|y\|$ \\
            $[|\langle x, y\rangle|=\|x\|\|y\| \Leftrightarrow x$ et $y$ sont colinéaires $]$. \\
        \end{tabular} \\
        \hline
        P 5.5 & Critère d'orthogonalité & \begin{tabular}{l}
            H espace préhilbertien, \\
            $[|\langle x, y\rangle|=0] \Leftrightarrow[\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{C},\|y\| \leq\|\lambda x+y\|]$. \\
        \end{tabular} \\
        \hline
        P 5.6 & Continuité du produit scalaire & \begin{tabular}{l}
            $H$ espace préhilbertien, I'application \\
            $\{H \times H \rightarrow \mathbb{C},(x, y) \mapsto\langle x, y\rangle\}$ est continue. \\
        \end{tabular} \\
        \hline
        P 5.7 & Théorème de Riesz & \begin{tabular}{l}
            espace de Hilbert, \\
            le dual $H^{*}$ de $H$ est isométriquement isomorphe à \\
            $H$ par l'identification (antilinéaire) \\
            $\left\{x^{*} \mapsto x, \forall y \in H,\left\langle y, x^{*}\right\rangle=(y \mid x)\right\}$. \\
        \end{tabular} \\
        \hline
        P 5.8 & Théorème de la projection & \begin{tabular}{l}
            H espace de Hilbert, $M$ sous-ensemble de $H$ \\
            convexe et fermé, $\forall x \in H, \exists y \in M, y$ unique, tel \\
            que $\|x-y\|=\inf (\|x-z\|, z \in M)$. \\
        \end{tabular} \\
        \hline
        P 5.9 & Orthogonal & \begin{tabular}{l}
            $H$ espace de Hilbert, $M$ sous-ensemble de $H, M^{\perp}$ \\
            est un sous-espace fermé de $H$; \\
            si $N=\overline{\operatorname{Vect}(M)}$, alors $N \cap M^{\perp}=\{0\}$. \\
        \end{tabular} \\
        \hline
        P 5.10 & Somme directe orthogonale & \begin{tabular}{l}
            espace de Hilbert, $M$ sous-espace vectoriel de $H$, \\
            $\left(M^{\perp}\right)^{\perp}=\bar{M}, H=\bar{M} \oplus M^{\perp}$. \\
        \end{tabular} \\
        \hline
        P 5.11 & \begin{tabular}{l}
            (i) Inégalité de Bessel \\
            (ii) Cas d'égalité dans Bessel \\
            (iii) Identité de Parseval \\
        \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l}
            Hilbert, $J=\left\{e_{n} ; n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}\right\}$ ensemble orthonormal \\
            de $H, M=\overline{\operatorname{Vect}(J)}$ et $x \in H$ et $x_{n}=\left\langle x, e_{n}\right\rangle, n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$. \\
            (i) $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left|x_{n}\right|^{2} \leq\|x\|^{2}$ \\
            (ii) $[x \in M] \Leftrightarrow\left[\|x\|^{2}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left|x_{n}\right|^{2}\right]$ \\
            (iii) $[J$ est une base orthonormale] $\Leftrightarrow$ \\
            $\left[\forall x \in H, \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left|x_{n}\right|^{2}=\|x\|^{2}\right]$. \\
        \end{tabular} \\
        \hline
        P 5.12 & \begin{tabular}{l}
            Caractérisation des bases or- \\
            thonormales \\
        \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l}
            H Hilbert, $J=\left\{e_{n} ; n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}\right\}$ ensemble orthonormal \\
            de $H,[J$ base orthonormale $] \Leftrightarrow$ \\
            $\left[\left\{\forall n,\left\langle x, e_{n}\right\rangle=0\right\} \Rightarrow\{x=0\}\right]$. \\
        \end{tabular} \\
        \hline
        P 5.13 & Structure de $\ell^{2}$ & \begin{tabular}{l}
            $\ell^{2}$, espace des suites de carré sommable. \\
            $x=\left(x_{n} ; n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}\right)(D 1.15)$ \\
            C'est un espace de Hilbert pour le produit scalaire \\
            $\langle x, y\rangle=\sum_{n=+\infty}^{n=+\infty} x_{n} \overline{y_{n}}$ \\
            $\left\{e_{n} ; n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}\right\}, e_{n}=\left(\delta_{n, 2}, p \in \mathbb{N}^{*}\right)$ est une base \\
            orthonormale de $\ell^{2}$. \\
        \end{tabular} \\
        \hline
        P 5.14 & \begin{tabular}{l}
            Structure hilbertienne de \\
            $L^{2}([-\pi,+\pi])$ \\
        \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{l}
            $L^{2}([-\pi,+\pi])$ (D 1.16) est un espace de Hilbert pour \\
            le produit scalaire $\langle f, g\rangle=\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi} f(x) \overline{g(x)} d x$, \\
            $\left\{e_{n} ; n \in \mathbb{Z}, e_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp (\right.$ in $\left.x)\right\}$ est une base \\
            orthonormale. \\
        \end{tabular} \\
        \hline
        P 5.15 & Théorème de Gram-Schmidt & \begin{tabular}{l}
            H espace de Hilbert, $\left\{g_{n} ; n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}\right\}$, système libre \\
            dans $H$, alors $\exists J=\left\{e_{n} ; n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}\right\}$ \\
            sous-ensemble orthonormal dans $H$ tel que \\
            $\forall N \in \mathbb{N}^{*}, \operatorname{Vect}\left(e_{1}, \ldots, e_{N}\right)=\operatorname{Vect}\left(g_{1}, \ldots, g_{N}\right)$. \\
        \end{tabular} \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This won't fix everything, but it may help.  11pt is really larger than typical book type, so you could try `\small` for the table, which should be 10pt.  Instead of using smaller tables in the table cells, set them up as paragraphs and let LaTeX do the line breaking.  Instead of `c` for the alignment, use `p{<dimen>}` and consider `\raggedright`.  Finally, consider whether it might be set landscape.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I really appreciate your help but I can't fix the problem ! Can you please fix the problem ? (my latex level is not good enough !)

Comment: Off-topic: `right=2cm,left=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm` may be expressed more succinctly as `margin=2cm`.

Answer (score 5):

Hm, your table is full of `tabular` environments which are just a clutter ... Remove them and for columns use type to which you can prescribe column widths.

As you note, you like to have long table. Among pykages dedicated for them, I would use `tabularray` since it enable simple code and nicer table formatting:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{dsfont}

\usepackage{etoolbox}   % for \ifblank
\usepackage{mathtools}  % supersede of amsmath
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\norm[1]\lVert\rVert{\ifblank{#1}{{\cdot}}{#1}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Vect}{Vect}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{systeme}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtblr}%
{
\setlist[enumerate]{nosep, label=(\roman*)\ , leftmargin=*}
}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter, 
                varwidth}


\begin{document}
   \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Does it exist or the table is without of it?}
                    ]{hlines, vlines,
                      colspec = {Q[l,h] X[l,m] X[2.5,l,m]},
                      colsep  = 3pt,
                      cells   = {font=\small},
                      row{1}  = {c},
                      measure = vbox,
                      rowhead = 1}
% column headers
$\mathbf{N}^{\circ}$ 
        &   Notion définie  &   Définition      \\
% table body
D 5.1   &   Produit scalaire dans un espace préhilbertien
            &   $H$ espace vectoriel complexe muni du produit scalaire 
                \textbackslash langle \textbackslash rangle, application 
                $\{H\times H \to\mathbb{C},(x, y) \mapsto\langle x, y\rangle\}$,\par
                vérifiant: 
                \begin{enumerate}
            \item   $\forall x \in H,\langle x, x\rangle \geq 0$
            \item   $\forall x, y \in H, \forall \lambda \in \mathbb{C},\langle x+\lambda y, z\rangle=\langle x, z\rangle+\lambda\langle y, z\rangle$
            \item   $\forall x, y \in H,\langle y, x\rangle=\overline{\langle x, y\rangle}$ (complexe conjugué de $\langle x, y\rangle)$
            \item   $[\langle x, x\rangle=0] \Leftrightarrow[x=0]$.
                \end{enumerate}
            \\
D 5.2   & Norme $\|$ $\|$ associée au produit scalaire 
            &  $\norm{}$, $\norm{x}=\langle x, x\rangle^{1 / 2}$ pour $H$ selon (D 5.1). 
            \\
D 5.3   &    Espace de Hilbert $H$ 
            &   Espace préhilbertien $H$ selon (D 5.1), de Banach (D 1.7) pour la norme associée. \\
D 5.4   &   $x$ et $y$ orthogonaux, $x \perp y$ 
            &   $H$ préhilbertien, $x, y \in H,\langle x, y\rangle=0$. 
            \\
D 5.5   &   Sous-ensembles $M$ et $N$ orthogonaux, $M \perp N$ 
            &   $H$ espace préhilbertien, $M \subset H, N \subset H$, 
            $\forall x \in M, \forall y \in N,\langle x, y\rangle=0$.
            \\
D 5.6   &   $M$ orthogonal, $M^{\perp}$ 
            &   $H$ espace préhilbertien, $M \subset H$,  
            $M^{\perp}=\{y \in H ; \forall x \in M,\langle x, y\rangle=0\}$. 
            \\
D 5.7   &   $M$ et $N$ supplémentaires  
            orthogonaux dans $H, H=M \oplus N$  
            ou $M \oplus^{\perp} N$ somme directe  
            orthogonale 
            &   $H$ est un espace de Hilbert, $M$ et $N$ sont deux 
            sous-espaces fermés de $H$ orthogonaux entre eux,  
            $H=M \oplus N$, on note aussi $H=M \oplus^{\perp} N$, la norme sur  
            $H$ est équivalente à celle fixée dans (D 1.12). 
            \\
D 5.8   &   Projection orthogonale $y$ de $x$ sur $M, y=P_{M X}$ 
            &   $H$ espace préhilbertien, $M$ sous-espace vectoriel 
            complet de $H, x \in H$ 
            Pour $H=M \oplus^{\perp} N$, selon (D 5.7), 
            $x=y+z, y \in M, z \in N$. 
            \\
D 5.9   &   Ensemble orthogonal $J$ 
            &   $H$ espace préhilbertien, $J \subseteq H$, 
            $\forall x, y \in J, x \neq y$, on $a\langle x, y\rangle=0$. 
            \\
D 5.10  &   Ensemble orthonormal $J$ (ou orthonormé) 
            &   $H$ espace préhilbertien, $J \subseteq H, J$ orthogonal et  
            $\forall x \in J,\|x\|=1$.
            \\
D 5.11  &   Ensemble total $J$ 
            &   $H$ espace de Hilbert, $J \subseteq H$, 
            Vect $(J)$, sous-espace vectoriel fermé engendré par  
            $J$, est $H$ entier. 
            \\
D 5.12  &   Base orthonormale $B$ 
            &   $H$ espace de Hilbert, $B$ ensemble orthonormal et  
                total. 
            \\
D 5.13  &   Espace de Hilbert séparable 
            &   $H$ espace de Hilbert, il existe une base orthonormale $B$ au plus 
            dénombrable.
            \\
%%%% secondpart
        \hline
P 5.1   &   Le fameux théorème de Pythagore 
            &   $H$ espace préhilbertien, $x, y \in H$  
            $[\langle x, y\rangle=0] \Rightarrow\left[\|x+y\|^{2}=\|x\|^{2}+\|y\|^{2}\right]$.
            \\
P 5.2   & Règle du parallélogramme 
            &  $H$ espace préhilbertien, $x, y \in H$, 
            $\abs{x+y}^{2}+ \norm{x-y}^{2} = 2\left(\norm{x}^{2} + \norm{y}^{2}\right)$. 
            \\
P 5.3   &   Règle de polarisation 
            &   espace préhilbertien, $x, y \in H$ $4\langle x, y\rangle=\sum \alpha\norm{x+\alpha y}^{2} ; \alpha=1,-1, i,-i$.
            \\
P 5.4   &   Inégalité de Schwarz ou bien de Cauchy-Schwarz  
            &   espace préhilbertien, $\forall x, y \in H$, 
            $\abs{\langle x, y\rangle} \leq\norm{x}\norm{y}$,
            $[\abs{\langle x, y\rangle}=\norm{x}\norm{y} \Leftrightarrow x$ et $y$ sont colinéaires].
            \\
P 5.5   &   Critère d'orthogonalité 
            &   H espace préhilbertien,  $[\abs{\langle x, y\rangle}=0] \Leftrightarrow[\forall lambda \in \mathbb{C},\norm{y} \leq\norm{\lambda x+y}]$.
            \\
 P 5.6  &   Continuité du produit scalaire 
            &   $H$ espace préhilbertien, I'application 
            $\{H \times H \rightarrow \mathbb{C},(x, y) \mapsto\langle x, y\rangle\}$ est continue. 
            \\
P 5.7   &   Théorème de Riesz     
            &   space de Hilbert, le dual $H^{*}$ de $H$ est isométriquement isomorphe à 
            $H$ par l'identification (antilinéaire)  
            $\left\{x^{*} \mapsto x, \forall y \in H,\left\langle y, x^{*}\right\rangle=(y \mid x)\right\}$. 
            \\
P 5.8   &   Théorème de la projection 
            &   H espace de Hilbert, $M$ sous-ensemble de $H$ convexe et fermé, $\forall x \in H, \exists y \in M, y$ unique, tel que $\norm{x-y} =\inf (\norm{x-z}, z \in M)$. 
            \\
P 5.9   &   Orthogonal 
            &   $H$ espace de Hilbert, $M$ sous-ensemble de $H, M^{\perp}$ est un sous-espace  fermé de $H$; si $N=\overline{\Vect(M)}$, alors $N \cap M^{\perp}=\{0\}$.
            \\
P 5.10  &   Somme directe orthogonale 
            &   espace de Hilbert, $M$ sous-espace vectoriel de $H$,  
            $\left(M^{\perp}\right)^{\perp}=\bar{M}, H=\bar{M} \oplus M^{\perp}$. 
            \\
P 5.11  &   \begin{enumerate}
        \item   Inégalité de Bessel  
        \item   Cas d'égalité dans Bessel  
        \item    Identité de Parseval  
            \end{enumerate} 
            &  Hilbert, $J=\left\{e_{n} ; n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}\right\}$ ensemble orthonormal  
            de $H, M=\overline{\Vect(J)}$ et $x \in H$ et $x_{n}=\left\langle x, e_{n}\right\rangle, n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$.  
                \begin{enumerate}
            \item   $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\abs{x_{n}}^{2} \leq\norm{x}^{2}$ 
            \item   $[x \in M] \Leftrightarrow\left[\norm{x}^{2}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\abs{x_{n}}^{2}\right]$ 
            \item   $[J$ est une base orthonormale] $\Leftrightarrow$ 
            $\left[\forall x \in H, \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\abs{x_{n}}^{2}=\|x\|^{2}\right]$. \\
                \end{enumerate}
            \\
P 5.12  &   Caractérisation des bases othonormales
            &  H Hilbert, $J=\left\{e_{n} ; n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}\right\}$ ensemble orthonormal 
            de $H,[J$ base orthonormale $] \Leftrightarrow$ 
            $\left[\left\{\forall n,\left\langle x, e_{n}\right\rangle=0\right\} \Rightarrow\{x=0\}\right]$. 
            \\
P 5.13  &   Structure de $\ell^{2}$ 
            &   $\ell^{2}$, espace des suites de carré sommable.  
            $x=\left(x_{n} ; n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}\right)(D 1.15)$  
            C'est un espace de Hilbert pour le produit scalaire 
            $\langle x, y\rangle=\sum_{n\in\infty} x_{n} \overline{y_{n}}$ 
            $\left\{e_{n} ; n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}\right\}, e_{n}=\left(\delta_{n, 2}, p \in \mathbb{N}^{*}\right)$ est une base  
            orthonormale de $\ell^{2}$. 
            \\
P 5.14  &   Structure hilbertienne de $L^{2}([-\pi,+\pi])$
            &    $L^{2}([-\pi,+\pi])$ (D 1.16) est un espace de Hilbert pour le produit scalaire $\langle f, g\rangle=\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi} f(x) \overline{g(x)} d x$,
            $\left\{e_{n} ; n \in \mathbb{Z}, e_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp(x)\right\}$ est une base
            orthonormale. 
            \\
P 5.15  & Théorème de Gram-Schmidt 
            &   H espace de Hilbert, $\left\{g_{n} ; n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}\right\}$, système libre dans $H$, alors $\exists J=\left\{e_{n} ; n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}\right\}$ 
            sous-ensemble orthonormal dans $H$ tel que 
            $\forall N \in \mathbb{N}^{*}, \Vect\left(e_{1}, \ldots, e_{N}\right)=\Vect\left(g_{1}, \ldots, g_{N}\right)$.  
            \\
    \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

In MWE I use `mathtools` package instead of `amsmath` add by it define math delimiters `\abs` and `\norm` and math operator `Vect`. Using them math expression is a bit shorter and more clear (hopefully I replace all their occurrence).

[image]

**Addendum:**
Considering @Mico and @Pascal suggestion and notes, your table should be actually written in two parts, liberated of "jail" vertical and horizontal lines and use automatic numbering of rows.

Also use `\bigl/\bigr` or \biggl/\biggr`instead of`\left/\right for delimiters sizes gives better their horizontal spacing.

**Edit:**
By removing space and `\bottomrule` between tables make both tables to be seen as one long table:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{palatino}              % "palatino" package is going to be obsolete
%\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}  % you may consider to use this palatino clone
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{dsfont}

\usepackage{etoolbox}   % for \ifblank
\usepackage{mathtools}  % supersede of amsmath
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\norm[1]\lVert\rVert{\ifblank{#1}{{\cdot}}{#1}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Vect}{Vect}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}  % loaded by amssymb

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{systeme}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtblr}%
{
\setlist[enumerate]{nosep, label=(\roman*)\ , leftmargin=*}
}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,
                varwidth}


\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{}  Q[l] X[l] X[2.5,l] @{}},
                      cells   = {font=\small},
                      cell{2-Z}{1} = {cmd=D 5.\the\numexpr\arabic{rownum}-1.},
                      row{1}  = {c},
                      rowsep  = 5pt,
                      stretch = -1,
                      measure = vbox}
% column headers
    \toprule
\No{}   &   Notion définie  &   Définition      \\
    \midrule
% table body
&   Produit scalaire dans un espace préhilbertien
    &   $H$ espace vectoriel complexe muni du produit scalaire
        \textbackslash langle  \textbackslash rangle, application
        $\{H\times H \to\mathbb{C},(x, y) \mapsto\langle x, y\rangle\}$,\par
        vérifiant:
        \begin{enumerate}
    \item   $\forall x \in H,\langle x, x\rangle \geq 0$
    \item   $\forall x, y \in H, \forall \lambda \in \mathbb{C},\langle x+\lambda y, z\rangle=\langle x, z\rangle+\lambda\langle y, z\rangle$
    \item   $\forall x, y \in H,\langle y, x\rangle=\overline{\langle x, y\rangle}$ (complexe conjugué de $\langle x, y\rangle)$
    \item   $[\langle x, x\rangle=0] \Leftrightarrow[x=0]$.
        \end{enumerate}
    \\
&   Norme $\|$ $\|$ associée au produit scalaire
    &  $\norm{x}=\langle x, x\rangle^{1 / 2}$ pour $H$ selon (D 5.1).
    \\
&   Espace de Hilbert $H$
    &   Espace préhilbertien $H$ selon (D 5.1), de Banach (D 1.7) pour la norme associée. \\
&   $x$ et $y$ orthogonaux, $x \perp y$
    &   $H$ préhilbertien, $x, y \in H,\langle x, y\rangle=0$.
    \\
&   Sous-ensembles $M$ et $N$ orthogonaux, $M \perp N$
    &   $H$ espace préhilbertien, $M \subset H, N \subset H$,
    $\forall x \in M, \forall y \in N,\langle x, y\rangle=0$.
    \\
&   $M$ orthogonal, $M^{\perp}$
    &   $H$ espace préhilbertien, $M \subset H$,
    $M^{\perp}=\{y \in H ; \forall x \in M,\langle x, y\rangle=0\}$.
    \\
&   $M$ et $N$ supplémentaires
    orthogonaux dans $H, H=M \oplus N$
    ou $M \oplus^{\perp} N$ somme directe
    orthogonale
    &   $H$ est un espace de Hilbert, $M$ et $N$ sont deux
    sous-espaces fermés de $H$ orthogonaux entre eux,
    $H=M \oplus N$, on note aussi $H=M \oplus^{\perp} N$, la norme sur
    $H$ est équivalente à celle fixée dans (D 1.12).
    \\
&   Projection orthogonale $y$ de $x$ sur $M, y=P_{M X}$
    &   $H$ espace préhilbertien, $M$ sous-espace vectoriel
    complet de $H, x \in H$
    Pour $H=M \oplus^{\perp} N$, selon (D 5.7),
    $x=y+z, y \in M, z \in N$.
    \\
&   Ensemble orthogonal $J$
    &   $H$ espace préhilbertien, $J \subseteq H$,
    $\forall x, y \in J, x \neq y$, on $a\langle x, y\rangle=0$.
    \\
&   Ensemble orthonormal $J$ (ou orthonormé)
    &   $H$ espace préhilbertien, $J \subseteq H, J$ orthogonal et
    $\forall x \in J,\|x\|=1$.
    \\
&   Ensemble total $J$
    &   $H$ espace de Hilbert, $J \subseteq H$,
    Vect $(J)$, sous-espace vectoriel fermé engendré par
    $J$, est $H$ entier.
    \\
&   Base orthonormale $B$
    &   $H$ espace de Hilbert, $B$ ensemble orthonormal et
        total.
    \\
&   Espace de Hilbert séparable
    &   $H$ espace de Hilbert, il existe une base orthonormale $B$ au plus
    dénombrable.
    \\
    \end{tblr}
\vspace{-1.2\baselineskip}
\begingroup
\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead, middlehead,lasthead}{default}{} % <---
\SetTblrStyle{foot}{font=\itshape\footnotesize}
   \begin{longtblr}{colspec = {@{} Q[l] X[l] X[2.5,l] @{}},
                    cells   = {font=\small},
                    cell{2-Z}{1} = {cmd=P 5.\the\numexpr\arabic{rownum}-1.},
                    row{1}  = {c},
                    row{2-Y}= {rowsep = 5pt},
                      stretch = -1,
                    measure = vbox,
                    rowhead = 1}
% column headers
    \toprule
\No{}   &   Désignation  &  Énoncé          \\
    \midrule
% table body
&   Le fameux théorème de Pythagore
    &   $H$ espace préhilbertien, $x, y \in H$
    $[\langle x, y\rangle=0] \Rightarrow\bigl[\|x+y\|^{2}=\|x\|^{2}+\|y\|^{2}\bigr]$.
    \\
& Règle du parallélogramme
    &  $H$ espace préhilbertien, $x, y \in H$,
    $\abs{x+y}^{2}+ \norm{x-y}^{2} = 2\bigl(\norm{x}^{2} + \norm{y}^{2}\bigr)$.
    \\
&   Règle de polarisation
    &   espace préhilbertien, $x, y \in H$ $\langle x, y\rangle=\sum \alpha\norm{x+\alpha y}^{2} ; \alpha=1,-1, i,-i$.
    \\
&   Inégalité de Schwarz ou bien de Cauchy-Schwarz
    &   espace préhilbertien, $\forall x, y \in H$,
    $\abs{\langle x, y\rangle} \leq\norm{x}\norm{y}$,
    $[\abs{\langle x, y\rangle}=\norm{x}\norm{y} \Leftrightarrow x$ et $y$ sont colinéaires].
    \\
&   Critère d'orthogonalité
    &   H espace préhilbertien,  $[\abs{\langle x, y\rangle}=0] \Leftrightarrow[\forall lambda \in \mathbb{C},\norm{y} \leq\norm{\lambda x+y}]$.
    \\
&   Continuité du produit scalaire
    &   $H$ espace préhilbertien, I'application
    $\{H \times H \rightarrow \mathbb{C},(x, y) \mapsto\langle x, y\rangle\}$ est continue.
    \\
&   Théorème de Riesz
    &   space de Hilbert, le dual $H^{*}$ de $H$ est isométriquement isomorphe à
    $H$ par l'identification (antilinéaire)
    $\bigl\{x^{*} \mapsto x, \forall y \in H,\left\langle y, x^{*}\right\rangle=(y \mid x)\bigr\}$.
    \\
&   Théorème de la projection
    &   H espace de Hilbert, $M$ sous-ensemble de $H$ convexe et fermé, $\forall x \in H, \exists y \in M, y$ unique, tel que $\norm{x-y} =\inf (\norm{x-z}, z \in M)$.
    \\
&   Orthogonal
    &   $H$ espace de Hilbert, $M$ sous-ensemble de $H, M^{\perp}$ est un sous-espace  fermé de $H$; si $N=\overline{\Vect(M)}$, alors $N \cap M^{\perp}=\{0\}$.
    \\
&   Somme directe orthogonale
    &   espace de Hilbert, $M$ sous-espace vectoriel de $H$,
    $\bigl(M^{\perp}\bigr)^{\perp}=\bar{M}, H=\bar{M} \oplus M^{\perp}$.
    \\
&   \begin{enumerate}
\item   Inégalité de Bessel
\item   Cas d'égalité dans Bessel
\item    Identité de Parseval
    \end{enumerate}
    &  Hilbert, $J=\{e_{n} ; n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}\}$ ensemble orthonormal
    de $H, M=\overline{\Vect(J)}$ et $x \in H$ et $x_{n}=\bigl\langle x, e_{n}\bigr\rangle, n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$.
        \begin{enumerate}
    \item   $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\abs{x_{n}}^{2} \leq\norm{x}^{2}$
    \item   $[x \in M] \Leftrightarrow\left[\norm{x}^{2}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\abs{x_{n}}^{2}\right]$
    \item   $[J$ est une base orthonormale] $\Leftrightarrow$
    $\biggl[\forall x \in H, \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\abs{x_{n}}^{2}=\|x\|^{2}\biggr]$. \\
        \end{enumerate}
    \\
&   Caractérisation des bases othonormales
    &  $H$ Hilbert, $J=\bigl\{e_{n} ; n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}\bigr\}$ ensemble orthonormal
    de $H,[J$ base orthonormale$] \Leftrightarrow$
    $\Bigl[\bigl\{\forall n,\left\langle x, e_{n}\bigr\rangle=0\Bigr\} \Rightarrow\{x=0\}\right]$.
    \\
&   Structure de $\ell^{2}$
    &   $\ell^{2}$, espace des suites de carré sommable.
    $x=(x_{n} ; n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}) (D 1.15)$
    C'est un espace de Hilbert pour le produit scalaire
    $\langle x, y\rangle=\sum_{n\in\infty} x_{n} \overline{y_{n}}$
    $\bigl\{e_{n} ; n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}\bigr\}, e_{n}=\bigl(\delta_{n, 2}, p \in \mathbb{N}^{*}\bigr)$ est une base
    orthonormale de $\ell^{2}$.
    \\
&   Structure hilbertienne de $L^{2}([-\pi,+\pi])$
    &    $L^{2}([-\pi,+\pi])$ (D 1.16) est un espace de Hilbert pour le produit scalaire $\langle f, g\rangle=\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi} f(x) \overline{g(x)} d x$,
    $\biggl\{e_{n} ; n \in \mathbb{Z}, e_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp(x)\biggr\}$ est une base orthonormale.
    \\
& Théorème de Gram-Schmidt
    &   H espace de Hilbert, $\left\{g_{n} ; n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}\right\}$, système libre dans $H$, alors $\exists J=\left\{e_{n} ; n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}\right\}$
    sous-ensemble orthonormal dans $H$ tel que
    $\forall N \in \mathbb{N}^{*}, \Vect(e_{1}, \ldots, e_{N})=\Vect(g_{1}, \ldots, g_{N})$.
    \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good job.  I see only two cells that look questionable: D 5,1 (`\langle]rangle`?) and P 5.11 (the last line should be indented).  This really is too big for one page.

Comment: +1. You may want to replace `\usepackage[english]{babel}` with `\usepackage[french]{babel}`.

Comment: @Mico, you are right, seems to be more sensible. Now I wonder why OP was used English babel in question... Corrected now.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, you are right. In OP text/code is easy going to lost ... Corrected now.

Comment: To use the `counter library`, I suggest `\newcounter{mycnta}
\newcounter{mycntb}
\newcommand{\mycnta}{\stepcounter{mycnta}D 5.\arabic{mycnta}}
\newcommand{\mycntb}{\stepcounter{mycntb}P 5.\arabic{mycntb}}` and `cell{2-14}{1} ={cmd=\mycnta},cell{15-Z}{1} = {cmd=\mycntb},`

Comment: With `french babel`, replace `$\mathbf{N}^{\circ}$` by `\textbf{\No{}}`

Comment: Another point: I think it's necessary to define two separate tabular-like environments, rather than just 1. The first has `Notion définie` and `Définition` in the headers for columns 2 and 3, whereas the second should have `Désignation` abd `Énoncé`.

Comment: @Mico, you may right. Than is not need to use longtable. It seems that I overlooked this.

Comment: @pascal974, good suggestions. I will use this idea in addendum to my answer. (will appear soon)

Comment: @Zarko I think is better to have one longtable and make the Designation abd Enonce as a multicolumn heading, otherwise if the table overflows you will have it on three pages with the second one only a few lines. Great post though.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides, I read the question again ... and now is less clear to me, what (s)he is after. Posted MWE consist two tables (as I done in addendum), solution in addendum occupy only two pages. Well, so far Mico answer is more popular than mine :-)

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you employ two `xltabular` environments (which can break across pages if needed), set their overall widths to `\textwidth`, and allow automatic line breaking in columns 2 and 3. I would further set the usable width of the first data column to half that of the second data column. I'd also get rid of all vertical rules and most horizontal rules to give the tables a more open and inviting "look". Trust me, the vertical rules won't be missed.

Furthermore, since you like to use Palatino as the text font, I suggest you employ a suitable package to employ Palatin as the math font as well. Lastly, for crying out loud, please replace both instances of `$\mathbf{N}^{\circ}$` with either`\textbf{N}\textsuperscript{o}` or, if you can make do without **bold-facing**  the letter "N", `\No{}`, a macro provided by the `babel` package (when loaded with the option `french`). (Aside: Many thanks to user @pascal974 for bringing the `\No{}` macro to my attention.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
 
%%\usepackage{textcomp}
%%\usepackage{amsfonts} % is loaded automatically by 'amssymb'

\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{amsmath} % is loaded automatically by 'mathtools'
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{pifont,dsfont,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{systeme}
%\everymath{\displaystyle} % not a good idea
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap}


%% new code
%%\usepackage{palatino} % 'palatino' package is borderline obsolete
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath} % Palatino clone

\usepackage{xltabular,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hsize=#1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{romanenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[romanenum]{label=(\roman*), nosep, left=0pt,
      before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}\RaggedRight},
      after ={\end{minipage}}}


\begin{document}
\linespread{1.05} % because Palatino

% first table, for D5.1 thru D5.13
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} l L{0.667} L{1.333} @{}}
\toprule
\No{} & Notion définie & Définition \\
\midrule
\endhead

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

D 5.1 
& Produit scalaire dans un espace préhilbertien 
& $H$ espace vectoriel complexe muni du produit 
scalaire $\langle\cdot,\cdot \rangle$, application 
$\{H \times H \to$ $\mathbb{C}$, $(x, y) \mapsto\langle x, y\rangle\}$, vérifiant
\begin{romanenum}
\item $\forall x \in H,\langle x, x\rangle \geq 0$ 
\item $\forall x, y \in H, \forall \lambda \in \mathbb{C},\langle x+\lambda y, z\rangle=
\langle x, z\rangle+\lambda\langle y, z\rangle$ 
\item $\forall x, y \in H, \langle y, x\rangle =\overline{\langle x, y\rangle}$ (complexe conjugué de $\langle x, y\rangle$) 
\item $[\langle x, x\rangle=0] \Leftrightarrow [x=0]$.
\end{romanenum}
\\
\addlinespace
D 5.2 
& Norme $\norm{\cdot}$ associée au produit scalaire 
& $\|x\|=\langle x, x\rangle^{1 / 2}$ pour $H$ selon (D 5.1). 
\\
\addlinespace
D 5.3 
& Espace de Hilbert $H$ 
& Espace préhilbertien $H$ selon (D 5.1), de Banach (D~1.7) pour la norme associée. 
\\
\addlinespace
D 5.4 
& $x$ et $y$ orthogonaux, $x \perp y$ 
& $H$ préhilbertien, $x, y \in H$, $\langle x, y\rangle=0$. \\
\addlinespace
D 5.5 
& Sous-ensembles $M$ et $N$ orthogonaux, $M \perp N$
& $H$ espace préhilbertien, $M \subset H$, $N \subset H$, $\forall x \in M, \forall y \in N,\langle x, y\rangle=0$. 
\\
\addlinespace
D 5.6 
& $M$ orthogonal, $M^{\perp}$ 
& $H$ espace préhilbertien, $M \subset H$, $M^{\perp}=\{y \in H ; \forall x \in M,\langle x, y\rangle=0\}$. 
\\
\addlinespace
D 5.7 
& $M$ et $N$ supplémentaires orthogonaux dans $H, H=M \oplus N$ ou $M \oplus^{\perp} N$ somme directe 
& $H$ est un espace de Hilbert, $M$ et $N$ sont deux sous-espaces fermés de $H$ orthogonaux entre eux, $H=M \oplus N$, on note aussi $H=M \oplus^{\perp} N$, la norme sur $H$ est équivalente à celle fixée dans (D~1.12). \\
\addlinespace
D 5.8 
& Projection orthogonale $y$ de $x$ sur $M, y=P_{M X}$ \ 
& $H$ espace préhilbertien, $M$ sous-espace vectoriel complet de $H, x \in H$

Pour $H=M \oplus^{\perp} N$, selon (D 5.7), $x=y+z, y \in M, z \in N$. 
\\
\addlinespace
D 5.9 
& Ensemble orthogonal $J$ 
& $H$ espace préhilbertien, $J \subseteq H$, 

$\forall x, y \in J, x \neq y$, on $a\langle x, y\rangle=0$. 
\\
\addlinespace
D 5.10 
& Ensemble orthonormal $J$ (ou orthonormé)
& $H$ espace préhilbertien, $J \subseteq H, J$ orthogonal et $\forall x \in J$, $\|x\|=1$. 
\\
\addlinespace
D 5.11 
& Ensemble total $J$ 
& $H$ espace de Hilbert, $J \subseteq H$, 

Vect $(J)$, sous-espace vectoriel fermé engendré par  $J$, est $H$ entier. 
\\
\addlinespace
D 5.12 
& Base orthonormale $B$ 
& $H$ espace de Hilbert, $B$ ensemble orthonormal et total. 
\\
\addlinespace
D 5.13 
& Espace de Hilbert séparable 
& $H$ espace de Hilbert, il existe une base orthonormale $B$ au plus dénombrable. \\

\end{xltabular}


% second table, for P5.1 thru P5.15
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} l L{0.667} L{1.333} @{}}
\toprule
\No{} & Désignation & Énoncé \\
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{r@{}}{\footnotesize suite à la page suivante}\\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

P 5.1 
& Le fameux théorème de Pythagore 
& $H$ espace préhilbertien, $x, y \in H$ 

$[\langle x, y\rangle=0] \Rightarrow\bigl[\norm{x+y}^{2}=\norm{x}^{2}+\norm{y}^{2}\bigr]$. 
\\
\addlinespace
P 5.2 
& Règle du parallélogramme 
& $H$ espace préhilbertien, $x, y \in H$, 

$\norm{x+y}^{2}+\norm{x-y}^{2}=2\bigl(\norm{x}^{2}+\norm{y}^{2}\bigr)$. 
\\
\addlinespace
P 5.3 
& Règle de polarisation 
& Espace préhilbertien, $x, y \in H$ 

$4\langle x, y\rangle=\sum \alpha\norm{x+\alpha y}^{2}$; $\alpha=1,-1, i,-i$. 
\\
\addlinespace
P 5.4 
& Inégalité de Schwarz ou bien de Cauchy-Schwarz 
& Espace préhilbertien, $\forall x, y \in H$, 
$\abs{\langle x, y\rangle} \leq\norm{x}\norm{y}$ 

$[\,\abs{\langle x, y\rangle}=\norm{x}\norm{y} \Leftrightarrow \text{$x$ et $y$ sont colinéaires}]$. 
\\
%\addlinespace
P 5.5 
& Critère d'orthogonalité 
& $H$ espace préhilbertien, 

$[\,\abs{\langle x, y\rangle}=0] \Leftrightarrow [\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{C}, \norm{y} \leq\norm{\lambda x+y}\,]$. \\
\addlinespace
P 5.6 
& Continuité du produit scalaire 
& $H$ espace préhilbertien, l'application 
$\{H \times H \to \mathbb{C},(x, y) \mapsto\langle x, y\rangle\}$ est continue. 
\\
\addlinespace
P 5.7 
& Théorème de Riesz 
& $H$ espace de Hilbert, le dual $H^{*}$ de $H$ est isométriquement isomorphe à $H$ par l'identification (antilinéaire) $\{x^{*} \mapsto x, \forall y \in H,\langle y, x^{*}\rangle=(y \mid x)\}$. 
\\
\addlinespace
P 5.8 
& Théorème de la projection 
& $H$ espace de Hilbert, $M$ sous-ensemble de $H$ convexe et fermé, $\forall x \in H, \exists y \in M, y$ unique, tel que $\norm{x-y}=\inf \bigl(\,\norm{x-z}, z \in M\bigr)$. \\
\addlinespace
P 5.9 
& Orthogonal 
& $H$ espace de Hilbert, $M$ sous-ensemble de $H, M^{\perp}$ est un sous-espace fermé de $H$; si $N=\overline{\operatorname{Vect}(M)}$, alors $N \cap M^{\perp}=\{0\}$. 
\\
\addlinespace
P 5.10 
& Somme directe orthogonale 
& Espace de Hilbert, $M$ sous-espace vectoriel de $H$, \

$\left(M^{\perp}\right)^{\perp}=\bar{M}, H=\bar{M} \oplus M^{\perp}$. 
\\
\addlinespace
P 5.11 
& \begin{romanenum}
  \item Inégalité de Bessel 
  \item Cas d'égalité dans Bessel 
  \item Identité de Parseval 
  \end{romanenum}
& Hilbert, $J=\left\{e_{n} ; n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}\right\}$ ensemble orthonormal de $H, M=\overline{\operatorname{Vect}(J)}$ et $x \in H$ et $x_{n}=\langle x, e_{n}\rangle$, $n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$. 

\begin{romanenum}
\item $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\abs{x_{n}}^{2} \leq\norm{x}^{2}$ 
\item $[x \in M] \Leftrightarrow\bigl[\,\norm{x}^{2}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\abs{x_{n}}^{2}\bigr]$ 
\item $[\text{$J$ est une base orthonormale}]\Leftrightarrow$

\quad$\bigl[\forall x \in H, \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\abs{x_{n}}^{2}=\norm{x}^{2}\bigr]$. 
\end{romanenum}
\\
\addlinespace
P 5.12 
& Caractérisation des bases orthonormales
& $H$ Hilbert, $J=\left\{e_{n} ; n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}\right\}$ ensemble orthonormal de $H$,

$[\text{$J$ base orthonormale}] \Leftrightarrow$ 

\quad$\bigl[\{\forall n,\langle x, e_{n}\rangle=0\} \Rightarrow\{x=0\}\bigr]$.
\\
\addlinespace
P 5.13 
& Structure de $\ell^{2}$ 
& $\ell^{2}$, espace des suites de carré sommable. 

$x=(x_{n} ; n \in \mathbb{N}^{*})$ (D~1.15) 

C'est un espace de Hilbert pour le produit scalaire $\langle x, y\rangle=\sum_{n=+\infty}^{n=+\infty} x_{n} \overline{y_{n}}$ 

$\left\{e_{n} ; n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}\right\}$, 
$e_{n}=(\delta_{n, 2}, p \in \mathbb{N}^{*})$ est une base orthonormale de $\ell^{2}$. 
\\
\addlinespace
P 5.14 
& Structure hilbertienne de $L^{2}([-\pi,+\pi])$ 
& $L^{2}([-\pi,+\pi])$ (D 1.16) est un espace de Hilbert pour le produit scalaire $\langle f, g\rangle
=\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi} f(x) \overline{g(x)} \,dx$, 

$\{e_{n} ; n \in \mathbb{Z}, e_{n}(x)=(1/\sqrt{2 \pi}\,) \exp (x)\}$ est une base orthonormale. \\
\addlinespace
P 5.15 
& Théorème de Gram-Schmidt 
& $H$ espace de Hilbert, $\{g_{n} ; n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}\}$, système libre dans $H$, alors $\exists\ J=\{e_{n} ; n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}\}$ sous-ensemble orthonormal dans $H$ tel que $\forall N \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$, $\operatorname{Vect}\left(e_{1}, \ldots, e_{N}\right)=\operatorname{Vect}(g_{1}, \dots, g_{N})$. 
\\

\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: With `{french}babel`, we have `\No{}`

Comment: @pascal974 - Thanks, I'll amend my answer.